# React: Update state with help of other state

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

I have three different state variables in a component. Two of the states is connected to a range slider that updates the state when i move the slider. One is for cost and one is for time.

My questions is, how do i update the third state based on information from the first two states?

```
function Calculator() {
  const [loanAmount, setLoanAmount] = useState(100000);
  const [loanTime, setLoanTime] = useState(5);

  const calculateCost = () => {
    const totalMonths = loanTime * 12;
    const monthlyFee = 0.00825;
    const monthlyFeePlusOne = 1.00825
    const totalPrice =
    (loanAmount*0.00825)*(Math.pow((1+0.00825), 60))/(Math.pow((1+0.00825), 60)-1);
    return Math.round(totalPrice);
  };
  const [calculation, setCalculation] = useState(calculateCost());


   <input
    className="slider"
    type="range"
    min="20000"
    max="200000"
    value={loanAmount}
    step="10000"
    onChange={(e) => setLoanAmount(e.target.value)}
  />
  <label>{loanAmount}</label>

  <input
    className="slider"
    type="range"
    min="2"
    max="10"
    value={loanTime}
    step="1"
    onChange={(e) => setLoanTime(e.target.value)}
    setCalculation
  />
  <label> {calculation} </label>
```

Answer (score 10):

The third value *isn't state* because you can always calculate it from other state/props.

Try replacing

```
const [calculation, setCalculation] = useState(calculateCost());
```

with

```
const calculation = calculateCost();
```

Making it state is redundant and complicates the code.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer suggests doing it using `useEffect` which is the typical way a lot of developers do it, but that's not what `useEffect` is for, as stated in the React documentation: **If your effect only adjusts some state based on another state, you might not need an effect.**

https://beta-reactjs-org-git-effects-fbopensource.vercel.app/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#you-might-not-need-an-effect

So, you should perform this operation in the `onChange` event of your inputs since the state update is tied to it and not the render itself (which is what `useEffect` is for).

```
const handleLoanAmountInputChange = (e) => {
  const amount = e.currentTarget.value;
  setLoanAmount(amount);
  const cost = calculateCost(amount, loanTime); // you will ned to update your function to use parameters, this way it will also easier to test the function
  setCalculation(cost);
}

<input
  onChange={handleLoanAmountInputChange}
```

Comment: Dan Abramov answer is better actually, but you may want to still pass the state variables as parameters so you can unit test that function

const calculation = calculateCost(loanAmount, loanTime);