# Dates stored in states not updating/rendering properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, array.prototype.map

I am trying to make a planner, which has buttons to switch months. I am using react and states to store dates. The individual months are being mapped properly, but switching between months gives some strange behaviour. The months update, but the dates don't seem to be being updated and the button has to be pressed multiple times for the map to update. Pressing the other button then jumps two months and the same behaviour occurs.

```
const MonthView = () => {

    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    const daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    const daysOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    const globalDate = new Date();
    // ^ switches between two months. strange behaviour. fix?
    // date does not appear to actially change.
    const [month, setMonth] = useState(globalDate.getMonth());
    const [year, setYear] = useState(globalDate.getFullYear());
    const [day, setDay] = useState(globalDate.getDate());
    const [dayOfWeek, setDayOfWeek] = useState(globalDate.getDay());
    const [days, setDays] = useState([]);
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const [firstDayOfMonthDay, setFirstDayOfMonthDay] = useState(daysOfWeek[new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()]);
    const [firstDayOfMonth, setFirstDayOfMonth] = useState(new Date(year, month, 1).getDay());
    const [lastDayOfMonth, setLastDayOfMonth] = useState(new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDay());
    const [lastDayOfMonthNumber, setLastDayOfMonthNumber] = useState(new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate());
    const [firstDayOfMonthNumber, setFirstDayOfMonthNumber] = useState(new Date(year, month, 1).getDate());

    const updateStates = () => {
        console.log("gdate: " + globalDate);
        setMonth(globalDate.getMonth());
        setYear(globalDate.getFullYear());
        setDay(globalDate.getDate());
        setDayOfWeek(globalDate.getDay());
        setFirstDayOfMonthDay(daysOfWeek[new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()]);
        setFirstDayOfMonth(new Date(year, month, 1).getDay());
        setLastDayOfMonth(new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDay());
        setLastDayOfMonthNumber(new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate());
        setFirstDayOfMonthNumber(new Date(year, month, 1).getDate());
        set_days();
    }

    const set_days = () => {
        let days = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < firstDayOfMonth; i++) {
            days.push(null);
        }
        for (let i = 1; i <= lastDayOfMonthNumber; i++) {
            days.push(i);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < (6 - lastDayOfMonth); i++) {
            days.push(i+1);
        }
        setDays(days);
        console.log(days)
        console.log(globalDate);
    }
        


    useEffect(() => {
        set_days();
    }, []);

    return(
        <>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" variant="light">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><Button variant="info" onClick={() => {globalDate.setMonth(globalDate.getMonth() - 1); updateStates();}}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} /></Button></th>
                    <th>{months[month]}</th>
                    <th><Button variant="info" onClick={() => {globalDate.setMonth(globalDate.getMonth() + 1); updateStates();}}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} /></Button></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    {daysOfWeek.map((day, index) => {
                        return <td key={index}>{day}</td>
                    }
                    )}
                </tr>
            
                {days.map((day, index) => {
                    if (index % 7 === 5) {
                        // MAKE CLICK ON CELL RETURN VAL and create new event on that day
                        // also week view and day view
                        // use lighthouse to test and do everything possible to decrease load time
                        return <tr key={index}> {days.slice(index - 5, index + 2).map((day, index2) => {
                            return <td key={index2} onClick={() => {console.log(index + index2 - 5);}}>{day}</td>
                        }
                        )}
                        </tr>
                    }
                   
                }
                )}

            </tbody>
        </Table>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: There's a lot going on there. As a first step, you might want to simplify the code and remove everything that you don't use. Then I would look remove the use of globalDate as a way to change things. Start here `() => {globalDate.setMonth(globalDate.getMonth() - 1); updateStates();` becomes just a call to something like `prevMonth()`. In that function I would rely on updates based on prev values. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: How would I then change it? Setting each individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenter stefan mentioned, we can greatly simplify this code to reduce the possibility of errors. You have a lot of state variables that are calculated from `globalDate`. If you can always calculate a value from other state, [**you should not store it as state.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72552825/) You can simply declare them as constants. You no longer need your `updateStates` logic, and your `set_days` function doesn't need to be in a `useEffect` hook. After removing redundant state, the only state variables you really need are `globalDate` and `events`.

Another issue is your button `onClick` behavior. When you call [`globalDate.setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth), you are **[mutating state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)**. State in React is immutable and should be updated by creating a new copy of state and changing the parts you need. To remedy this, you can instantiate a new `Date` object, call `setMonth` on that object, then set `globalDate` to that new object.

The following simplifies your code and fixes the issue you are experiencing:

```
  const MonthView = () => {
    const months = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December"
    ];
    const daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    const daysOfWeek = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const [globalDate, setGlobalDate] = useState(new Date());

    const month = globalDate.getMonth();
    const year = globalDate.getFullYear();
    const day = globalDate.getDate();
    const dayOfWeek = globalDate.getDay();
    const firstDayOfMonthDay = daysOfWeek[new Date(year, month, 1).getDay()];
    const firstDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 1).getDay();
    const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDay();
    const lastDayOfMonthNumber = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
    const firstDayOfMonthNumber = new Date(year, month, 1).getDate();
    const days = (() => {
      let daysArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < firstDayOfMonth; i++) {
        daysArr.push(null);
      }
      for (let i = 1; i <= lastDayOfMonthNumber; i++) {
        daysArr.push(i);
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < 6 - lastDayOfMonth; i++) {
        daysArr.push(i + 1);
      }
      return daysArr;
    })();

    return (
      <>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th>
                <Button
                  variant="info"
                  onClick={() => {
                    const newDate = new Date();
                    newDate.setMonth(globalDate.getMonth() - 1);
                    setGlobalDate(newDate);
                  }}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
                </Button>
              </th>
              <th>{months[month]}</th>
              <th>
                <Button
                  variant="info"
                  onClick={() => {
                    const newDate = new Date();
                    newDate.setMonth(globalDate.getMonth() + 1);
                    setGlobalDate(newDate);
                  }}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />
                </Button>
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              {daysOfWeek.map((day, index) => {
                return <td key={index}>{day}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>

            {days.map((day, index) => {
              if (index % 7 === 5) {
                // MAKE CLICK ON CELL RETURN VAL and create new event on that day
                // also week view and day view
                // use lighthouse to test and do everything possible to decrease load time
                return (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    {" "}
                    {days.slice(index - 5, index + 2).map((day, index2) => {
                      return (
                        <td
                          key={index2}
                          onClick={() => {
                            console.log(index + index2 - 5);
                          }}
                        >
                          {day}
                        </td>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tr>
                );
              }
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </>
    );
  };
```

You have some unused variables that I left in just in case you need them later. It looks like some values like `firstDayOfMonth`, `lastDayOfMonth`, and `lastDayOfMonthNumber` are used only in the function that generates the `days` array, so they can probably be moved into the body of that function if they aren't needed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a cleaner way to get the dates for the weeks in the month.

Consider separate functions to get the start of a week, dates in the week and weeks in a month. The following functions return Dates or arrays of Dates, but they could be timestamps.

```js
// Return a new Date that is the Monday prior to date
// or the same date if it's a Monday
// If week to start on Sunday, pass true for weekStartOnSunday
function getStartOfWeek(date = new Date(), weekStartOnSunday = false) {
  return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - (weekStartOnSunday? date.getDay() + 1 :
  (date.getDay() || 7)) + 1)
}

// Return array of dates for week of Mon to Sun
// for supplied date.
// If week to start on Sunday, pass true for weekStartOnSunday
function getWeekDates(date = new Date(), weekStartOnSunday = false) {
  let start = getStartOfWeek(date, weekStartOnSunday);
  let week = [];
  for (let i=0; i<7; i++) {
    week.push(new Date(start));
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return week;
}

// Return array of weeks for month of supplied date
function getMonthWeeks(date = new Date(), weekStartOnSunday = false) {
  let start = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
  let startMonth = date.getMonth();
  let weeks = [];
  while (start.getMonth() == startMonth) {
    weeks.push(getWeekDates(start, weekStartOnSunday));
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 7);
  }
  return weeks;
}

// Get calendar weeks for current month
// Monday as start of week
getMonthWeeks().forEach((week, i) => {
  console.log('Week ' + (i+1));
  week.forEach(day => console.log(day.toDateString()));
});
```

Once you have the dates of the month as arrays of weeks, you can then generate the month calendar fairly simply.